# Loops in Bash for creating sequentially numbered folders

Tags: bash, shell-script

How would I write a BASH script that creates directories test0-test63?
I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
for x in range (64)
     mkdir ./test'x'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
for x in {1..64}; do
    mkdir ./test$x
done
```

or

```
mkdir ./test{1..64}
```